# Mule datamapper: Mapping a value to an attribute of right hand side

Tags: mule, datamapper, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I have an xml like:

```
<name>Mule</name>
<company>mulesoft</company>
```

How can I map using datamapper to get result like:

```
<details name="Mule" company="mulesoft" />
```

I tried but datamapper never shows the attributes to map.

I am using Mule 3.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to either supply the schema or provide an example for both sides.

For example use the following as the sample source. DataMapper will generate the XSD based on the example file:

```
<enity>
<name>Mule</name>
<company>mulesoft</company>
</enity>
```

Right side do the same but use

```
<company>
<details name="Mule" company="mulesoft" />
</company>
```

Then click Create Mappings and you should see the mappings to your attributes.

Comment: That was so straight forward,thanks.I have an xml validated in xmllint but when I supply it on right hand side of datamapper it says null pointer exception:orignal value will be preserved. What could be the cause?